# VBA string - adding a newline of \n equivalent is not working

Tags: excel, newline, vba

I've got the following VBA code extract,

```
series.Points(2).DataLabel.Text = "A:" & t1 & vbNewLine & "B:" & t2
```

I was expecting the following output,

```
A:1
B:2
```

But I'm getting the following instead,

```
A:1

B:2
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: what happens if you remove `vbNewLine`?

Comment: just one straight line

Comment: Ah, see Ralph's answer then. I think it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
series.Points(2).DataLabel.Text = "A:" & t1 & chr(13) & "B:" & t2
```